# History of Pale Fire's Criticism

Tags: literary-criticism, vladimir-nabokov, pale-fire

How did Pale Fire's interpretation and analysis develop through time? Had there been continuous critical attention towards it and what did Nabokov himself say about the work?

It is quite a substantial and curio-like piece of literature. Did anyone manage to decipher it in different ways from its publication towards now? What was it compared to? (Italo Calvino springs to mind)

Comment: Did you know that, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Fire), there were already roughly 80 studies on *Pale Fire* by 1995?